# Divisor of $3^{2n+1}+61$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have difficulty to show the following:

If $p$ is a prime and $p^2$ divides $3^{2n+1}+61$, then $p$ must be $2$.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: For a single value of $n,$ or for all values of $n,$ or what?

Comment: You are basically saying that the odd part of  $3^{2n+1}+61$ is squarefree. It would be a very nice result(for me) if true....

Comment: Definitely not for negative ones ;-)

Comment: For single $n$ surely, @Will. Quick Mathematica tests suggest that all the numbers $3^\ell+61$ are square-free save for factors that are powers of two when $\ell$ is odd. Checked it up to $\ell=30$.

Comment: @JBKing: But how does it prove that $p$ must be $2$? Surely, one possible value of $p$ is $2$, but how do you know that it is the only value of $p$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, no source is given for this. My guess, pending detail, is that this is false for occasional large $n$ but finding them will be difficult.

Answer (score 6):

As Will Jagy suspected this is false.

$$17^2\mid 3^{123}+61.$$

Comment: Square-and-multiply allows you to verify this by hand. I used Mathematica to find the exponent $123$.

Comment: The residue class of $3$ generates the unit group of the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{17^2}$. This has order $17(17-1)=272$. Thus
$$17^2\mid 3^{123+k\cdot 272}+61$$ for all natural numbers $k$.

Comment: In fact, the OP claim should fail for many $p$. Whenever $3$ is a generator modulo $p^2$ and $-61$ is not a square, we can fid suitable $n$.

Comment: Jyrki, good.... I believe, from Euler's version of Fermat's Little Theorem, we can add $272 = \phi(289)$ to the exponent of $3$ and get $17^2$ again, same for adding $2 \cdot 272,$ and so on

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks a lot, Jyrki. from I.H.

Comment: Good thinking, @Hagen! Assuming the density version of Artin's conjecture it is then implied that the conjecture fails for a positive fraction of primes. Admittedly my mind was set on finding the smallest exponent.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and Jyrki, wrote a function that does limited factoring (trial division by primes up to 1000) and used odd exponents up 10 10,000. Plenty of odd square factors. Allowing primes up to 10,000 did not seem to change anything as far as square factors, as one would expect to require much larger exponents to get something new. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a thing in C++ with GMP that does trial division by primes only up to some bound i provide. So this limited factoring is very fast, and definitive up to that bound; for this run i put in bound = 1000. However, when the final factor is written as "BIG" we do not know the factorization of that.

$$ 3^{123} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 467  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{197} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 761  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{267} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 29 \cdot 127^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{275} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{395} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 23 \cdot 59 \cdot 311  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{617} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{667} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{683} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \cdot 101^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{703} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{715} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 29^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{779} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 103^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{801} + 61   = 2^6 \cdot 59^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{939} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 29  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{959} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 613  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1093} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 11 \cdot 173^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1209} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 859  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1211} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1301} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1421} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 53^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1483} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 101  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1527} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 29^2 \cdot 103 \cdot 127  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1643} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 557  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1715} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1755} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1829} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 821^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1831} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 109^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{1985} + 61   = 2^6 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2027} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2209} + 61   = 2^6 \cdot 71^2 \cdot 109 \cdot 647  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2221} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2299} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2327} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2339} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 29^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2571} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 241  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2669} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 53  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2727} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{2843} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^3 \cdot 29  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3011} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 29  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3051} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 241^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3115} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3151} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 29^2 \cdot 463  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3233} + 61   = 2^6 \cdot 11 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3353} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 11 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 59  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3387} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 23  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3659} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3695} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3739} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 29  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3931} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{3963} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \cdot 29^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4037} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4177} + 61   = 2^8 \cdot 53^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4203} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 439  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4223} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \cdot 59^2 \cdot 613  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4245} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4281} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 53 \cdot 59 \cdot 103^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4379} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 71  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4475} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4605} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 761^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4721} + 61   = 2^7 \cdot 19^3  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4747} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 29 \cdot 109  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4751} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{4775} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19 \cdot 29^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5019} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5063} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 103  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5257} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5291} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 227  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5405} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5563} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5587} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 23 \cdot 29^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5747} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5763} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 163  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{5835} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6089} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6107} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6269} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 19 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 71  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6379} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 23  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6399} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 29^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6431} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6651} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 29 \cdot 241  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6773} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 11 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 613  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6775} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 59  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6889} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 89^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6923} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{6933} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 11 \cdot 53^2 \cdot 103  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7115} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7179} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 71^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7195} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7211} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 29^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7281} + 61   = 2^7 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7457} + 61   = 2^6 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 23 \cdot 173  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7467} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^3  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7645} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 59^2 \cdot 653 \cdot 761  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7717} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 109^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7739} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 71 \cdot 389  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7783} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 101 \cdot 103^2 \cdot 251  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7787} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{7799} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 29  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8011} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8023} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 29^2 \cdot 647  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8141} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8283} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 59 \cdot 101 \cdot 251  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8293} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 11 \cdot 23^2 \cdot 103  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8483} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 101 \cdot 401  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8555} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 19 \cdot 29  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8799} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8825} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 89 \cdot 641  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8827} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{8835} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 29^2 \cdot 127 \cdot 937  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9099} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9167} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 19^2 \cdot 439  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9305} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 23^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9371} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 23  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9509} + 61   = 2^4 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9643} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9647} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 29^2 \cdot 599  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9689} + 61   = 2^5 \cdot 19 \cdot 53^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9811} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 23^3 \cdot 227  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9851} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 19^2  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$ 
 $$ 3^{9915} + 61   = 2^3 \cdot 17^2 \cdot 829  \cdot  \mbox{BIG}       $$

Answer (score 0):

First part: is easy to show that 
$$
3^{2n+1}+61\equiv 0\pmod 4
$$
why? Well $61\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ (easy to verify). And is also easy to verify that 
$$
3^{2n+1}\equiv 3\pmod 4
$$
In fact every odd number can be written as $4k+3$ or $4k+1$ with $k$ integer. Let's suppose that for some $n$ we can write ($3^n$ is odd)
$$
3^n = 4k+3
$$
now we can easily verify that
$$
3^{n+1}=3(4k+3)=4(2+3k)+1
$$
and since $3=4\cdot 0+3$ is easy to see that for every odd power we have
$$
3^{2n+1}=4k+3
$$
and therefore summing (modulus 4) with $61$ you get
$$
3^{2n+1}+61\equiv 3+1\pmod 4\equiv 0 \pmod 4
$$

Now what remains to be shown is that no other prime satisfy what the OP is asking. Working on that now ;-)

**EDIT**: another nice way to show that (and much shorter) is:
let's write 
$$
g(n)=3^{2n+1}+61
$$
now is easy to see that
$$
g(n+1)=3^{2n+1+2}+61=3^{2n+1}3^2+61=3^{2n+1}3^2+3^2 61-8\cdot 61 = g(n)3^2-8\cdot 61
$$
and so is also true that
$$
g(n+1)  \equiv g(n)3^2-8\cdot 61 \pmod 4 \equiv 0 \pmod 4
$$
and since is true for $n=0$ is true for all $n$.

**EDIT 2**: let's see if we can move on with the second part. Let's use what I just wrote. Let's suppose that exist a prime $p_2>2$ for which for some $n$
$$
g(n)\equiv 0 \pmod {p_2^2}
$$
now let's consider $n+1$ we find that (similar to what we did before)
$$
g(n+1)\equiv -8\cdot 61 \pmod {p_2^2}
$$
that is not zero. I am actually not sure that is enough... Thinking a bit about this and then I will finish to edit my answer. Of course it could be true for one $n$...

Comment: Maybe I'm just being finicky, but can you use a different Greek symbol for your function? Using $\phi$ means that there's always the risk of mixing it with Euler's totient function...

Comment: Done. Changed to $g$.

Comment: It is not asked to show that $4 \mid 3^{2n+1} + 61$.